# Enforcing Form Validation in Jenkins During Execution

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Jenkins has a built-in mechanism to do form validation using the `doCheckVar(@QueryParameter String value)` methods.

These methods render errors in real time when using `FormValidation.error("error")`.

Is there a built-in mechanism to enforce such requirements the during build time (by maybe failing the build)? Or do these need to be handled using Java's error throwing mechanism?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't use form validation methods during the build time. They simply aren't designed for this purpose: there is no way you can access some form fields in Jenkins during the compilation process.